# Terminator is not launching after updating

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, terminator

I am not able to launch [terminator](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/terminator.1.html) for this occurs:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 122, in <module>
    TERMINATOR.create_layout(OPTIONS.layout)
  File "/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py", line 311, in create_layout
    window, terminal = self.new_window()
  File "/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminator.py", line 234, in new_window
    terminal = maker.make('Terminal')
  File "/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/factory.py", line 94, in make
    output = func(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/factory.py", line 106, in make_terminal
    return(terminal.Terminal())
  File "/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminal.py", line 147, in __init__
    self.update_url_matches()
  File "/usr/share/terminator/terminatorlib/terminal.py", line 273, in update_url_matches
    reg = Vte.Regex.new_for_match(re, len(re), self.regex_flags)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gi/module.py", line 139, in __getattr__
    self.__name__, name))
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Vte' object has no attribute 'Regex'
```

I have tried to remove and purge many times and then reinstalled it but still, it's not opening.

Comment: Its a python problem. Documented here: https://github.com/tuhiproject/tuhi/issues/197. Simply used google with the error thrown...

Answer (score 1):

This issue has been resolved in the repository, but that the fix for Ubuntu 16.04 has not yet been released with an incremental build. This seems to have something to do with newly-added support for Python 3, but I haven't delved too deep into the source or related pull requests to figure out exactly what the root cause is. Here's the link to the issue in the Terminator GitHub mirror where this patch is discussed: https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator/issues/10

In order to run Terminator on a fully-updated Ubuntu 16.04 environment at the moment it appears that you'll need to pull and build Terminator from the master branch of the application itself. You'll need git installed to do this:

`git clone https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator.git`

You'll need the ubuntu 16.04 packages for both python and `python-vte` installed to build and install the app correctly:

`sudo apt update && sudo apt install python python-vte`

From there just `cd` into the newly-cloned Terminator repo directory with `cd ./terminator`, and install the app as a sudoer like this:

`sudo ./setup.py install --record=install-files.txt`

You can review the full install and uninstall process in the `INSTALL` file within the root directory of the terminator repo.

Whenever the next Ubuntu 16.04 build is released on the Launchpad PPA you should be able to go back to installing terminator with `apt` as you normally would, though you should probably uninstall the hand-built version when you do, like this:

`sudo ./setup.py uninstall --manifest=install-files.txt`

I've just stepped through this process and now have terminator working on my fully upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop environment.